# How to use ChartJS in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to use [ChartJS](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/fonts.html) within a React component and do not know, how to use it.
First, I need create a canvas element as described on https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/usage.html#creating-a-chart. Then, I need to reference to DOM with

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
```

I am pretty new in React world and I know that manipulating the DOM directly, it is not allowed.

How should I do it?

Answer (score 4):

You can use React Ref in order to access directly to your element.